# Problems with JAXB and UTF-16 encoding

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling, utf-16

Hi I have a small APP that reads content from an xml file and put it into a corresponding Java object.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Marker>
<TimePosition>2700</TimePosition>
<SamplePosition>119070</SamplePosition>
</Marker>
```

here is the corresponding Java code:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MarkerDto.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("D:/marker.xml");
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_16.toString());
MarkerDto markerDto = (MarkerDto) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

If I run this code I get an "Content is not allowed in prolog." exception. If I run the same with UTF-8 everything works fine. Does anyone have a clue what might be the problem?

Comment: The fact that it works fine when you run it with UTF-8 means that the file is actually in UTF-8 and not UTF-16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's several things wrong here (ranging from slightly suboptimal, to potentially very wrong). In increasing order of likelihood of causing the problem:

1. When constructing an `InputStreamReader`, there's no need to call `toString()` on the `Charset`, because that class has [a constructor that takes a `Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.charset.Charset)), so simply remove the `.toString()`:

   ```
   Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
   ```

   This is a tiny nitpick and has no effect on functionality.
2. Don't construct a `Reader` at all! XML is a format that's self-describing when it comes to encoding: Valid XML files can be parsed without knowing the encoding up-front. So instead of creating a `Reader`, simply pass the `InputStream` directly into your XML-handling code. Delete the line that creates the `Reader` and change the next one to this:

   ```
    MarkerDto markerDto = (MarkerDto) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
   ```

   This *may or may not* fix your problem, depending on whether the input is well-formed.
3. Your XML file might have `encoding="UTF-16"` in the header and not actually be UTF-16 encoded. If that's the case, then it is malformed and a conforming parser will decline to parse it. Verify this by opening the file with the advanced text editor of your choice (I suggest Notepad++ on Windows, Linux users probably know what their preference is) and check if it shows "UTF-16" as encoding (and the content is readable).

   > If I run the same with UTF-8 everything works fine.

   This line suggests that that's what's actually happening here: the XML file is mis-labeling itself. This needs to be fixed at the point where the XML file is created.

   Notably, this demo code provides exactly the same `Content is not allowed in prolog.` exception message that is reported in the question:

   ```
   String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<foo />";
   JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance();
   Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
   InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
   jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
   ```

   Note that the XML encoding attribute claims `UTF-16`, but the actual data handed to the XML parser is UTF-8 encoded.